# MySQL server version : Mysql error while inserting into the table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

[image]

```
INSERT INTO project_categories (id, category_id, project_id, company_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (385, 1, 88, NULL, now(), now());
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO project_categories (id, category_id, project_id, company_id, c' at line 1

Comment: Can you check your insert statement? It is not closed at the end and might be cut aswell

Comment: it looks the code is incomplete.

Comment: Updated ``` INSERT INTO project_categories (id, category_id, project_id, company_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (385, 1, 88, NULL, now(), now()); ```

Comment: Is there anything **before** the insert statement?

Comment: That doesn't look like the statement from before Mysql never adds ’ with a NOW()

Comment: INSERT INTO project_categories VALUES (385, 1, 88, NULL,'2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000', '2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000');

Comment: Tried this also but not inserting, similar issue is coming.

Comment: Show also the create table please

Comment: Added image, Please have a look into this.

Comment: Do you use some statement which includes more than one query?

Comment: No only one row insert at one time.

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c0b7378a808297ed3db5d57c871908a2). Please provide a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
’2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000’
```

Use

```
'2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000'
```

Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

This works see
[image: works]

It is your query, only without the now part that should work anyway.

```
INSERT INTO project_categories (id, category_id, project_id, company_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (385, 1, 88, NULL,'2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000', '2020-04-03 18:14:01.000000');
```

Comment: Not helpful this way.

Comment: Yes it does see picture

Comment: Send me this query please.

Comment: added in answer